# Category description weirdly cached?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cache

I have a category, for arguments sake lets call it Beans.

Beans has a title, and it has a description.

If I make a change to the title of Beans, it gets reflected on the front end fine.

If I make a change to the description of Beans, it does NOT get reflected on the front end. If I completely delete the description of Beans, I can still see the old description on the front end. No changes I make to the description comes thru to the front end what-so-ever.

I have all the cache's turned off.

I have cleared the cleared the caches from the Admin Panel.

I have manually deleted the contents of `/var/cache/`.

I have disabled and re-enabled the category.

I have disabled the category, deleted the contents of `/var/cache/`, cleared the caches from the Admin Panel, and then re-enabled the category.

The old description for the Beans category still shows, but any changes I make to the title is reflected fine each time.

How can I stop the description for the category Beans from being cached? Other categories are unaffected by this, only Beans seems to want to keep hold of its old description.

This is in Magento 1.9

Comment: What happens if you switch back to native `default/default` Magento theme ?

Comment: Are you sure it is getting picked up from DB, and not something static in any CMS block or the template file itself ? Also, check if it is overridden in a more local scope like store or store-view.

Comment: ive managed to solve this - it was a specific store view incorrectly overriding just the description on that page - anyone who can add this as an answer will get marked as correct...